# Centered ImageView inside a Toast in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-imageview, toast

I'm making a simple `Webview` application for Android. When there's no connection I'm showing a custom toast message which will cover all the screen, but inside the toast I want to show an image with `ImageView`. The problem is that the toast is covering all the screen since I'm using the following code to do it:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
```

How could I put the `ImageView` inside the toast totally centered? This is `ImageView` in the toast layout named `toast_custom_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" 
        android:background="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is code in my activity that will show the toast when there is no connection:

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
}
```

I will really appreciate your advice, friends.

Comment: Use RelativeLayout and its layout_centerInParent attribute...

Comment: Thanks yahya, this worked neatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `RelativeLayout` instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" 
        android:background="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Catherine, the `RelativeLayout` with the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` did the magic, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" 
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

where the relevant part is `android:gravity="center"`